# How to convert these method from C# to VB.net (Windows Phone 7)

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-phone-7

Hi I am looking at a tutorial which uses the camera and I came accross some methods that I need. Only problem is that they are in C# and I need them to be in VB. I have used a converter but it doesnt convert it properly.

```
private void VideoCamera_Initialized(object sender, object eventArgs)
{
    if (Initialized != null)
    {
        Initialized.Invoke(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}

public bool LampEnabled
{
    get { return (bool)_videoCameraLampEnabledPropertyInfo.GetGetMethod().Invoke(_videoCamera, new object[0]); }
    set { _videoCameraLampEnabledPropertyInfo.GetSetMethod().Invoke(_videoCamera, new object[] { value }); }
}
```

Here is the converted code and the errors:

```vb
Private Sub VideoCamera_Initialized(sender As Object, eventArgs As Object)
    If Initialized IsNot Nothing Then
        Initialized.Invoke(Me, New EventArgs())
    End If
End Sub

Public Property LampEnabled() As Boolean
    Get
        Return CBool(_videoCameraLampEnabledPropertyInfo.GetGetMethod().Invoke(_videoCamera, New Object(-1) {}))
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        _videoCameraLampEnabledPropertyInfo.GetSetMethod().Invoke(_videoCamera, New Object() {value})
    End Set
End Property
```

Errors:

> Error    2   'Public Event Initialized(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.

In terms of the second method. It doesnt look like its been converted properly even though there isnt any errors

Comment: Why not? What error do you get? Please show us the converted code.

Comment: Ive added the converted code and errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error states, you need to use `RaiseEvent`; code converters don't know if it is, in fact, an event, or if it's a delegate. And, of course, since VB.NET is an amazing language, you don't need the `Is Nothing` check or the `New Object(-1) {}`, or the `New Object()` part before `{value}`.

```vb
Private Sub VideoCamera_Initialized(sender As Object, eventArgs As Object)
    RaiseEvent Initialized(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
End Sub

Public Property LampEnabled() As Boolean
    Get
        Return CBool(_videoCameraLampEnabledPropertyInfo.GetGetMethod().Invoke(_videoCamera, {}))
    End Get
    Set(value As Boolean)
        _videoCameraLampEnabledPropertyInfo.GetSetMethod().Invoke(_videoCamera, {value})
    End Set
End Property
```

Comment: @Matt9Atkins: That's likely not a translation issue.

Comment: The code was downloaded from: http://www.locked.nl/wp7-flashlight-getting-started

Comment: @Matt9Atkins: Nope :) That's the second most useless error message in .NET that I've ever seen.

Answer (score 0):

Change it to

```
RaiseEvent Initialized(Me, EventArgs.Empty)
```

Comment: `RaiseEvent` isn't a function; the parentheses go after `Initialized`.